# How to cause deadlock in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection, deadlock

What I have tried is selecting and updating the table from another connection meanwhile. What are the ways to intentionally cause a deadlock on a table?

Comment: Just request a lock on everything an never release it?